# Fedora 15 :Twitter on Google Chrome

Tags: fedora, selinux, chrome

It's been almost 15 days since I installed Fedora 15 on my laptop. And since day 1, Twitter seems to be having some issue opening up. Whenever I try to load twitter.com, it loads an "Aw Snap" page.

From the answers [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2ad350b9885322bd&hl=en), I did `sudo setenforce 0` and Twitter started working fine. But turning off SELinux doesn't seem to be a good thing to me. I tried disabling all extensions and removing all the apps from Google Chrome. Still the problem persists.

Can someone please provide some solution to this irritating problem?

Comment: You should file a bug report on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a better way to fix your problem.
The bug is that chrome's configuration files are created with the wrong label on it.
To fix that, just run :

```
$ restorecon -R ~/.config
```

And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

There are better options to simply disabling SELinux. You can set SELinux to use permissive mode so that it complains instead of blocking the execution of google chrome. Better yet, you can create a new local policy that allows google-chrome to run under SELinux, Here are some links to get you started:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/SELinux_FAQ/index.html

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01

Read the last link for the procedure, but do document yourself before jumping in, a fair understanding og what you are doing will reduce unnecessary frustration.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I shall try that out tomorrow morning.

Comment: 2 questions before I start reading those massive articles. 1) Google chrome's working fine but it's twitter that's not working fine in Google chrome. hope the docs apply to me in that case. 2) Docs are for F13. I am using F15. F15 docs don't have SELinux article like F13 has.